# How to save value of variable to local stoarage?

Tags: javascript, html, input, local-storage

I have an input = slider that sets a certain variable x. That distance is then calculated by a number to determine a price.(price = x *0.05)  I want to add whatever price currently set to local stoarage by the click of a button, and then be able to change the input and repeat the process **but still keeping the old values in local storage**.

I tried this:

```
function fetch() { //js for making the slider work 
  pricePerKm = {
    "plane": 0.16,
    "car": 0.12,
    "train":0.05,
    "bus":0.1,
    "ship":0.08
  };
  let km = document.getElementById("slider1").value;
  
  document.getElementById("km").innerHTML = km+" km";
  let price = Math.round(km * pricePerKm[moT]/10)*10; 
  
  document.getElementById("preis").innerHTML = price+" €";

  const addButton = document.getElementById('add') //trying to add value to local storage
  addButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    localStorage.setItem('priceoutput', price) 
  }
  )
}
```

```
<h1 style="font-size: 70px;" class="preis" id="preis"> 0 € </h1> 
            
<button class="add" id="add"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i></button>
```

It's my first time using local storage so im not surpirsed I failed.
Thanks! :)

Comment: Be aware that `localStorage` keeps data forever, that is you'll find the stored data even after restarting your PC. If you prefer to keep data only until the browser is closed (or address changed), go for `sessionStorage`. Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: "*I failed*" - why, what happened? Did you see errors? Or, if you think your value did not get saved to local storage, how did you check that?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I checked in the development window of my browser, nothing happens when i set a value and click the button

Comment: So maybe the event listener isn't working, have you tried checking that?  Eg add a `console.log()` inside your handler to see if it runs?  It looks like you add the event listener inside the `fetch()` function ... how do you call `fetch()`?

Comment: Also note even if your code works you would not see anything in your browser ... or are you checking localstorage values in devtools?  I already asked, but how are you checking that it is not working?